# AttributeError: module 'scipy.stats' has no attribute 'itemfreq'

Tags: python, scipy

I am getting error like - `AttributeError: module 'scipy.stats' has no attribute 'itemfreq'`
while I am trying to use `stats.itemfreq` method from `scipy` as shown in the example [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scipy-stats-itemfreq-function-python/).

Any idea, how can I resolve the issue? any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: On this page it says that `itemfreq` was removed in the release of version 1.9.0. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/release.1.9.0.html

Answer (score 2):

Since the method `itemfreq` was deprecated and removed, you can achieve the same thing in that example using `np.unique()` and `np.column_stack` like this:

```
import numpy as np 

arr = [14, 31, 27, 27, 31, 13, 14, 13] 

# get the unique values and counts
values, counts = np.unique(arr, return_counts=True)

# combine the values and counts
result = np.column_stack((values, counts))

print("Item frequency:\n", result)
print("\nBincount:\n", np.bincount(arr))
```

Comment: In practice, there is rarely needed to put `values` and `counts` back into a single array.  Doing so forces the two different results to have a common data type, even though `counts` is naturally an integer and `values` is the same type as the input array.